# Run a rask task on first and third monday of every month in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have defined a rake task but I am not sure how I can make it run on the first and third Monday of every month in Ruby. Please help me.

schedule.rb

```
#run this task on every 1st and 3rd monday of the month

  rake 'office:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
```

office.rake

```
namespace :office do
  desc "reminder emails"
  task reminder: :environment do
      PaymentReminderWorker.perform_async(arg1, arg2)
  end
end
```

Please help me figure that out.

Forgetting the first Monday I was thinking of something like this.

```
require 'date'
Date.today.mday <= 7
```

Updated answer(is this a good approach?)

```
namespace :office do
  desc "reminder emails"
  task reminder: :environment do
   today_date = DateTime.now
   first_monday = Chronic.parse("1st monday of this month", :now => today_date.to_date.beginning_of_month)
   third_monday = Chronic.parse("3rd monday of this month", :now => today_date.to_date.beginning_of_month)
   if today_date == first_monday || today_date == third_monday
     PaymentReminderWorker.perform_async(arg1, arg2)
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can't you just write a [`crontab` schedule](https://superuser.com/questions/890185/setting-a-cron-to-be-run-on-every-1st-and-the-3rd-monday) for that?

Comment: @tadman you mean something like whenever?

Comment: @tadman I have added an answer section in my question. Please have a look.

Comment: It's worth testing that out to see if it works. One thing I like to do is have a date-override variable I can use, like `now = ENV['AT'] ? DateTime.parse(ENV['AT']) : DateTime.now` so you can test like `NOW=2020-02-29 rake office:reminder` That way you can quickly skip around to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
namespace :office do
  desc "reminder emails"
  task reminder: :environment do
   if (Date.today.monday?) & ((Date.today.mday.in? (1..7)) || (Date.today.mday.in? (15..22)))
     PaymentReminderWorker.perform_async(arg1, arg2)
   end
  end
end
```

Or just use the regular task without the date part and in cron it would be:

```
every '0 0 0 ? * 2#1 *' do
  rake 'office:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end

every '0 0 0 ? * 2#3 *' do
  rake 'office:reminder', environment: ENV['RAILS_ENV']
end
```